# firebase=firebase(config) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/myprofile/Documents/firebase tests.py", line 9, in  firebase=firebase(config) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I am getting this error in IDLE when I run this code.

```
from firebase import firebase
    
config = {
    "apiKey": "apiKey",
    "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
    "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com"
}
    
firebase = firebase(config)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Python : 3.8

Comment: The editor or IDE you use to write the program is not relevant to its behavior.

Comment: Can you suggest one which will be suitable?

Comment: @ Terry Jan Reedy Can you suggest one?

Comment: IDLE is fine (I help maintain and improve it), but since it is not part of the problem/question, it should not be one of the tags.  The same would be true if you used another editor or another IDE that can run python code.  To be sure that any editor or IDE is having no effect, run code directly with python.  In this case, on Windows, with the `py` launcher installed, `py -3.8 C:/Users/myprofile/Documents/firebase tests.py` in Command Prompt, for instance, should work.  (I realize that you no longer have your original setup.)

Comment: The error message puzzle me.  After `from firebase import firebase`, the name `firebase` should be bound to a `firebase` within `firebase`.  You expected the bound object to be a callable.  The error message says it is a module named 'firebase' within a package named 'firebase'.  This would be unusual and confusing design.  I should have suggested adding `print(firebase)` after the import.  Is the code posted the entire initial code in the files?

Comment: I have tried doing the same thing from the pythonanywhere site. It works well SO i THINK THE PROBLEM IS SOMEWHERE WITH PERMISSIONS IN MY COMPUTER OR SOME SOFTWARE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because python is thinking `firebase(config)` is referring to the package itself, instead of the `Firebase` object within that package.

To fix this, just change `from firebase import firebase` to `from firebase import Firebase` and `firebase = firebase(config)` to `firebase = Firebase(config)`.

Comment: It still says:-   File "C:\Users\myprofile\Documents\firebase tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from firebase import Firebase
ImportError: cannot import name 'Firebase' from 'firebase' (C:\Users\myprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\firebase\__init__.py)'

Comment: Hm, that's weird. Can you try installing the package again? The quickstart guide states to use `Firebase` so it could be that your installation corrupted.

Comment: Also, just making sure, this is the `firebase` package on pip (this one: https://pypi.org/project/firebase/), right?

Comment: Now I degraded the version to 3.0.0 now there's another error.  >>>   from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'.

Comment: Try installing `pycryptodome`?

Comment: So I did pip install pycrypto and it shows another error >>>.ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0].....(its too long to comment here)............\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\pycrypto' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: I believe `pycrypto` refers to a dead project (https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/issues/292#issuecomment-548376073). Try installing `pycryptodome` instead?

Comment: Hmm, try uninstalling `firebase`, `pycryptodome`, and `pycrypto` (if it did install), and then installing `firebase`? It's possible that previous installs of the packages are messing around with the current ones. Also, please make sure that you're installing `firebase`, not `python-firebase` (a different library).

Comment: You'll also want to uninstall `crypto` if you have it, since they end up conflicting with a `pycryptodome` installation from `firebase`.

Comment: Can't Uninstall PyCrytoDome>>> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\crypto\\__init__.py'

Comment: Try closing any python shells and run the commands in a raised shell (Command Prompt as Administrator)?

Comment: The initial claim in the answer is off.  If `from x import x` run without raising, `x` will be bound to a submodule or object within package/module `x`, not to the top level package/module.  The only time this would be sensible is if module x contains function x as it main entry point, and even then I would likely prefer 'main'.  So either the code is misquoted or firebase has a confusing design.